# Add primary key as row number in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a primary key for my table. Primary key would be the row number. First row should have seq_no 1, row n should have sequence number n and so on

Emp_demo2

```
emp_id    emp_name   emp_sal_K    emp_manager
1         Ali         200          2
20         Zaid        770          4 and so on
```

**Query to add and update columns**

```
Alter table emp_demo2
Add seq_no int
Update emp_demo2 set seq_no = row_number
```

**Error**

> Invalid column name 'seq_no'.

Comment: Separate the `ALTER` and `UPDATE` with a `GO` statement. 
Also what is `row_number` there isn't such column in your table

Comment: `row_number` is a function in SQL Server. We use it with over. I am trying to use it. If you think it is not the correct function, kindly suggest what to use

Comment: then your update statement is incomplete

Comment: so how to complete it, thats my question..**Expected output** I just need that row number 1 should have sequence 1, row 2 should have sequence 2, row n should have sequence n

Comment: use `identity` `ALTER TABLE emp_demo2 ADD seq_no int identity`

Comment: As a rule you don't want to force a [surrogate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) to be [dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set). Failed transactions and deleted rows will lead to gaps in the values. Reassigning values to keep them dense requires updating any tables with foreign key relations on the column. Archived data becomes increasingly difficult to interpret. In some cases it may make sense to have dense values, e.g. `DisplayOrder` for a set of rows that will appear on a form, but that isn't a suitable primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this line instead of add and update

```
Alter table emp_demo2 add seq_no int identity not null;
```

Comment: Just a note:  The `op` wants the added column to be the primary key, so this should be:  `Alter table emp_demo2 add seq_no int identity primary key`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `GO` Statement in between the `Alter` and `Update` Query in the above:

```
Alter table emp_demo2
Add seq_no int
GO

Update emp_demo2 set seq_no = row_number
```

Comment: What you exactly need for that Column Seq_No? @ShailajaGuptaKapoor

Comment: I just need that row number 1 should have sequence 1, row 2 should have sequence 2, row n should have sequence n

Comment: Alter table emp_demo2
Add seq_no int IDentity(1,1)
GO

This can Solve your Case @ShailajaGuptaKapoor

Answer (score 1):

Use `IDENTITY` property on an integer datatype of the column.

But there is no possibility to guaranty that there will be no "lack" in the continuity of the int values.

If you want to have no lack, you need to use a view with `ROW_NUMBER()` windowing function.